# glassfish 5 can´t start using comand line

Tags: java, glassfish-5

Hi when I try to start glassfish 5 in ..\glassfish\bin with the command asadmin start-domain i get this error :

Waiting for domain1 to start .Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

I think there same problem inside the asadmin.bat with this comand
%JAVA% -jar "%~dp0..\glassfish\lib\client\appserver-cli.jar" %*

But can´t figure out what is wrong in my pc

I have a clean installation ( I have removed all java´s and install this new  version )of java jdk1.8.0_181 and jre1.8.0_181

Comment: Is **JAVA_HOME** set correctly? From the [Release Notes for Glassfish 5.0](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/release-notes.pdf): _"Before performing any GlassFish Server installation or configuration procedures, **set the JAVA_HOME environment variable on the GlassFish Server host machine to point to the correct Java version. Also be sure to add the JAVA_HOME/bin directory to the PATH variable for your environment**. The JAVA_HOME variable must be set on all local and remote GlassFish Server hosts."_

Comment: yes  I have JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181 and 
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181